# Sql Like to RegEx

Tags: sql-server, regex, function, stored-procedures, sql-like

Is there a good way to convert Regular Expression into LIKE inside a Function (MSSQL)? 
The sproc does not get more complicated than this:

```
(country\=)(?<Country>[\w\d]+)(\&sessionid\=)(?<SessionId>.+)
```

The groups will not be used in the LIKE, they are there for another purpose.

I would like to use this inside a sproc late like:

```
SELECT * FROM [Table]
WHERE test_regex(regex, 'text') = 1
```

Where the regex is a part of [Table]

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Some kind of table based dispatch mechanism where rules are expressed as regular expressions? ...Just curious if I guessed correctly.

Comment: I would presume parsing log files. That looks like a query string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to add Regular Expression parsing to SQL server, using a CLR function. This is possible from SQL 2005 and up. See [here](http://justgeeks.blogspot.com/2008/08/adding-regular-expressions-regex-to-sql.html) for a great example.

Comment: Finally got an answer from them, should work fine.. Thanks. And even though your answer don't quite answer my question, it solves my problem.. So I mark it as solved :)

Answer (score 4):

Check this function of sql. It may help you to achieve your task : `PATINDEX('%[^0-9\.]%',@Input)`

[PATINDEX (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx)

Comment: Is there a way to tell the function that multiple instances of a expression, like regex:s "+" or "*". 

For example PATINDEX('%[a-c]+%',@Input)

Answer (score 4):

I'd imagine

```
SELECT ...
FROM [Table]
WHERE col LIKE 'country=[A-Za-z0-9]%&sessionid=[A-Za-z0-9]%'
```

might be close enough? If the aim is just to bring back records with non blank country and sessionid values.

If the value in the column wouldn't necessarily start with 'country' you'd have to use `WHERE col LIKE '%country=[A-Za-z0-9]%&sessionid=[A-Za-z0-9]%'` which could slow things down considerably as per KM's answer.

Answer (score 2):

that will run very slow on a large table, parsing the string column on each and every row.

if you can change the table, it might be better to split that string column into different columns, so you can have a more traditional `WHERE country=... AND sessionid=...`, you could even add and use an index this way.

Answer (score 2):

Use the RegEx functionality within [SQL#](http://www.sqlsharp.com/features/) which is free.  I've not had any performance issues with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Not out of the box.  The closest you get to a regex search in SQL Server is PATINDEX(), but that doesn't do regular expressions.

If you really wanted this, you'd have to make a CLR function to run the regex instead.  You may be concerned about speed, but I would say that almost nothing you would do which concerns regular expressions or patterns would be able to use an index anyway.