# Is there an alternation for wildcards using LIKE in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, wildcard, sql-like

My query looks for dataset containing a particular label, let say:

```
  SELECT * FROM Authors
  WHERE Title LIKE @pattern
```

where @pattern is defined by user. So, `%abc%` would match `abcd`, `0abc`, etc. Sometimes there are labels like

1. Xabc-ONE
2. blaYabc-TWO-sometext
3. Zabc-THREE
4. blubXabc-FOUR

and I'm looking for labels containing abc and ONE or TWO, something like `%abc%(ONE|TWO)%`. Is it possible?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6778362/14955

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not able to use user-defined functions on sql server.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand your question right, but why not simply

```
SELECT * FROM Authors
WHERE Title LIKE '%abc%ONE%' OR '%abc%TWO%'
```

?

`LIKE` is just a search with wildcards, nothing more, so there's actually no other way of doing what you want with `LIKE`. If you need more, have a look into [regular expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html). But be aware that it's slower than `LIKE` and in your case absolutely not necessary.

**UPDATE:**

From comments "don't want to care for what the user wants to match"...then simply do it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Authors
WHERE Title LIKE CONCAT('%', $userInput, '%ONE%') OR CONCAT('%', $userInput, '%TWO%')
```

Or do I still don't get you right?

Comment: I don't want to care for what the user wants to match and change my query accordingly. Well, I will test how much effort the CLR function will take within our sql environment.

Comment: Your query still depends on user's input. In case, user looks for `%abc%FOUR%` it does not work anymore. This is what I mean. But "like" cannot handle with logic operations, so have to use your first suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can add support for regular expressions to SQL Server via a CLR function, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3255424/1030), but it may not be possible for you in your environment. Check with your friendly sysadmin!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server you can enable the full text search engine and use the keyboards contains and near to find abc near ONE

I will say in the query(pseudo code)

```
Select something from table where CONTAINS(column_name, 'abc NEAR ONE')
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142568.aspx